# How to implement function similar while cycle

Tags: scala

I try implement while loop with infinity loop checking, so if cycle executes more than `CONST` times it throws exception:

```
val MAX_CYCLES = 1000000

@throws(classOf[InfinityLoopException])
def guardedWhile(condition: () => Boolean)(body: () => Unit): Unit = {
  var cnt = 0
  while (condition.apply()) {
    body.apply()
    if (cnt > MAX_CYCLES) throw new InfinityLoopException()
    cnt += 1
  }

}

class InfinityLoopException() extends RuntimeException("Loop executed " + MAX_CYCLES + " cycles")
```

It works, but I want to have non function signatures, like classic while:

```
var i = 0
guardedWhile(i < 5){
  println(i)
}
```

For now i have:

```
var i = 0
guardedWhile(() => i < 5)(() => {
  println(i)
  i += 1
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the parameters to call-by-name.

```
def guardedWhile(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit = { ...
```

And then reference them directly.

```
  while (condition) {
    body
    . . .
```

Call-by-name means that they are re-evaluated every time they are referenced.